# My screen gets "pixelated" after waking up from the sleep. (Zorion OS)

Tags: gnu-screen, sleep

After waking up from sleep, my laptop's screen and all the apps that were running on it before going to sleep have distorted pixels.[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Are you using NVIDIA binary drivers? If you are, that's expected - restart your browser.

Comment: How do I prevent something like this from happening? It's not just my browser, every application gets distorted.  @ArtemS.Tashkinov